# Paper Dialogue Button unexpected behaviour

Tags: polymer, web-component, paper-elements

I was working on a project and designing a layout for floor lights like this:

Main page: index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <title>Test setup</title>

  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the `app/` directory -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2E3AA1">

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="app/manifest.json">

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="app/images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="app/images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="app/images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="app/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- Because this project uses vulcanize this should be your only html import
       in this file. All other imports should go in elements.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="app/elements/elements.html">

  <link rel="import" href="floor-map/floor-1.html">
  <link rel="import" href="floor-map/floor-2.html">
  <link rel="import" href="lighting-gui/light-panel.html">

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

</head>

<body unresolved>
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
      <!-- Drawer Scroll Header Panel -->
      <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>

      <!-- Main Area -->
      <paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header>
        <!-- Main Toolbar -->
        <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall">
          <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>

          <span class="space"></span>

          <!-- Application name -->
          <div class="middle middle-container">
            <div class="app-name">Test</div>
          </div>

          <!-- Application sub title -->
          <div class="bottom bottom-container">
            <div class="bottom-title">The future of intelligent lighting system</div>
        </div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <div style="background-color: #842dce">
            <paper-tabs attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor1" href="{{baseUrl}}">Floor-1</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor2" href="{{baseUrl}}floor2">Floor-2</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor3" href="{{baseUrl}}floor3">Floor-3</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor4" href="{{baseUrl}}floor4">Floor-4</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor5" href="{{baseUrl}}floor5">Floor-5</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab link><a data-route="floor6" href="{{baseUrl}}floor6">Floor-6</a></paper-tab>
             </paper-tabs>

        </div>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="content">
          <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">

          <!-- This is floor maps: -->
          <section data-route="floor1">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Floor 1.</h2>
                <floor1-view></floor1-view>
              </paper-material>
          </section>
          <section data-route="floor2">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>This is floor 2.</h2>
                <floor2-view></floor2-view>
              </paper-material>
          </section>
          <section data-route="floor3">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>This is floor 3.</h2>
              </paper-material>
          </section>
          <section data-route="floor4">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>This is floor 4.</h2>
              </paper-material>
          </section>
          <section data-route="floor5">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>This is floor 5.</h2>
              </paper-material>
          </section>
          <section data-route="floor6">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>This is floor 6.</h2>
              </paper-material>
          </section>


       <!-- this is the lighting layout of floor-->   
          <section data-route="light-panel">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>**Group 1:**</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel2">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>**Group 2:**</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel3">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 3:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel4">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 4:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel5">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 5:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel6">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 6:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel7">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 7:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel8">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 8:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel9">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 9:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          <section data-route="light-panel10">
              <paper-material elevation="1">
                <h2>Group 10:</h2>
                <light-panel></light-panel>
              </paper-material>
          </section>

          </iron-pages>
        </div>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </paper-drawer-panel>

    <paper-toast id="toast">
      <span class="toast-hide-button" role="button" tabindex="0" onclick="app.$.toast.hide()">Ok</span>
    </paper-toast>

  </template>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

some helper element I have created as:

1. group-map.html

> ```
> <style>
>   .big {
>     --iron-icon-height: 200px;
>     --iron-icon-width: 200px;
>   }
> </style>
>
> <template>
>       <paper-button data-dialog="actions" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
>           <iron-icon class="big" src="../lighting-images/lighting.png"></iron-icon>
>       </paper-button>
>
>       <paper-dialog id="actions"> 
>           <h2>Light Profile</h2> 
>               <light-page></light-page>
>       </paper-dialog> 
> </template>
>  </dom-module> 
>
>
> <script> 
>      Polymer({ 
>         is: "group-map"
>     }); 
> </script> 
>
> <script>
>   function clickHandler(e) { 
>       var button = e.target; 
>       while (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog') && button !== document.body) { 
>         button = button.parentElement; 
>       } 
>
>       if (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog')) { 
>         return; 
>       } 
>
>       var id = button.getAttribute('data-dialog'); 
>       var dialog = document.getElementById(id); 
>
>       if (dialog) { 
>           console.log("dialog open called.");
>           dialog.open(); 
>           console.log("dialog open called.");
>       } 
>     } 
> </script>
> ```

2. light-page.html

> ```
> <dom-module id="light-page"> 
>   <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
>
>   <style>
>     .button1 {
>       @apply(--layout-horizontal);
>       @apply(--layout-start-justified);
>     }
>
>     .button3 {
>       @apply(--layout-horizontal);
>       @apply(--layout-end-justified);
>     }
>   </style>
>
>   <template> 
>       <div class="container horizontal start-justified layout">
>               <!-- Iron images -->
>           <img src="../lighting-images/led.png" class="image" alt="lighting-logo" />  
>       </div>      
>
>       <div class="container horizontal end-justified layout">
>               <!-- Iron images -->
>           <img src="../lighting-images/percentage.jpg" class="image" alt="percentage-logo" /> 
>       </div> 
>
>       <div align="right">
>               <!-- paper slider -->
>               <paper-slider id="light-brightness" pin value="0"></paper-slider>
>               <styleis="custom-style">
>                   paper-slider {
>                     --paper-slider-height: 5px;
>                   }
>               </style>
>       </div>
>
>       <div class="buttons button1">
>               <!-- paper buttons -->
>               <paper-button class="custom indigo horizontal end-justified layout" id="light-on" raised>On</paper-button>
>               <paper-button class="custom indigo" raised id="light-off">Off</paper-button>
>               <paper-button class="custom indigo horizontal end-justified layout" raised>Submit</paper-button>
>       </div>
>  </template> 
>
> </dom-module> 
>
>
> <script> 
>   Polymer({ 
>         is: "light-page" 
>      }); 
> </script>
> ```

3. light-panel.html

> ```
> <dom-module id="light-panel" >
>  <style>
>         .image {
>             padding: 2px;
>             border-color: blue;
>             border-width: 2px;
>             border-style: solid;
>             width: 150px;
>             height: 150px;
>         }
>         .content-wrapper {
>             background: white;
>         }
>   </style>
>
>   <template>
>      <div class="horizontal layout center-justified wrap content-wrapper">
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>         <group-map></group-map>
>     </div>
>   </template>
> </dom-module>
>
> <script>
>     Polymer({
>         is: "light-panel"
>     });
> </script>
> ```

4. floor-1.html

> ```
> <dom-module id="floor1-view">
>         <style>
>             .image {
>                 padding: 2px;
>                 border-color: blue;
>                 border-width: 2px;
>                 border-style: solid;
>                 width: 150px;
>                 height: 150px;
>             }
>             .content-wrapper {
>                 background: white;
>             }
>         </style>
>         <template>
>                 <div class="horizontal layout center-justified wrap content-wrapper">
>                     <a href="/light-panel"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-1.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel2"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-2.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel3"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-3.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel4"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-4.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel5"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-5.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel6"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-6.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel7"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-7.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel8"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-8.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel9"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-9.png"></a>
>                     <a href="/light-panel10"><img class="image" src="../lighting-images/group-10.png"></a>
>                 </div>
>         </template>
>     </dom-module>
>
>     <script>
>         Polymer({
>             is: "floor1-view"
>         });
>     </script>
> ```

The **light-panel.html** has the map of light based on one floor which is divided into groups. The group is represented by **floor-1.html**. The group is a grid of image url anchor tags. All the urls redirects to a section of polymer **index.html** page.
The section is a grid of **paper-dialogue** element. The dialogue page is designed to be a layout depicted in **light-page.**html. The dialogue element is defined in **group-map.html**.

The problem is that it works fine for **Group-1** in index page but the click event on dialogue from **Group-2** and others is not working. Although each group has exactly same element created in **light-panel.html**.

Note: All imports are fine no error in chrome source/console terminal.

Guys where am I going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: sorry for the editing.  In group-map.html first line is not showing which is: <dom-module id="group-map">